# Unable to pass this-> pointer to a sub object

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I know `this` is already a pointer, but I want to understand what `this` is exactly. Is it an address or is it a * type pointer?

If I were to store this into a variable how would I have to define that variable?

Lets take this as an example

```
class Adult
{
private:
 Child child;

public:
 Adult(){
  child = new Child(this);
  //to have something to hold onto and get back to the upper level of the hierarchy.
 }
};


class Child
{
private:
 Adult* my_adult;

public:
 Child();
 Child(Adult &hand){
  my_adult = hand;
 }
}
```

Okay, so where I run into the trouble is with the line of code that goes `my_adult = hand;`
It outputs this when I try to build the project, I will be horribly shocked if there are more behind this one.

```
sys/chin.cpp:19:14: error: cannot convert ‘Adult’ to ‘Adult*’ in assignment
```

So how does this work when being dealt with as a data type opposed to accessing members?

Comment: The thing you call "address" is indeed a _reference_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`my_adult` is a pointer, `hand` is not, pure and simple.

You either need:

```
class Child
{
private:
 Adult my_adult; //no pointer

public:
 Child();
 Child(Adult &hand){
  my_adult = hand;
 }
};
```

or

```
class Child
{
private:
 Adult* my_adult;

public:
 Child();
 Child(Adult* hand){ //pointer parameter
  my_adult = hand;
 }
};
```

Your first example is also illegal:

```
child = new Child(this);
```

shouldn't compile, since child is an object, not a pointer.

```
child = Child(this);
```

would be the correct version.

Comment: it's better perhaps to store a reference in the first example, this would match the semantics of the original code better.

Comment: can't you point to an address with a pointer, isn't that the point?

Comment: @Vlad then you'd have scope issues.

Comment: @JoshC the `&` in this case doesn't represent an address, but a reference.

Comment: Also if you use the `Child(Adult&)` version, you'd have to change `child = Child(this)` to `child = Child(*this)`. Also you might want to mention initialiser lists.

Comment: The problem with a solid `Adult` object in `Child` is that it was copied in, any subsequent changes to the original `Adult` won't be reflected in this copy, which is unlikely to be what the OP wanted.

Comment: Now if I compile using *this I get "undefined reference to 'child::child()'"

Comment: @KateGregory not only that, but you'd have an `Adult` that contained a `Child` that contained an `Adult` that contained a `Child`...

Comment: @JoshC you haven't defined the body of `Child::Child()`

Comment: hhaa of course.. I had just typed in the prototype for it and never defined it, thanks seth.

Comment: Luchian thank you a lot, that little extra time to put out a full example helped tie things together especially with that *this suggestion. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

An address and a * type pointer are the same thing. Change your Child constructor to take an `Adult*` and initialize it with initialization syntax, not an `=`:

```
Child(Adult* hand): my_adult(hand) { }
```

Once you have that pointer, code in your Child class can call `my_adult->Whatever()` as needed. You need to know that this approach is only safe if the `Adult` objects always outlive the `Child` objects. For example, if an order is deleted, all the order items are deleted too, so you don't need to worry about an order item using an invalid pointer to its order. If that's not how things are in your system then you have a bigger problem than pointer syntax to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `my_adult` is a *pointer*, but `hand` is a *reference*. `my_adult=&hand` would work, for example.

Comment: There are more problems than this; for example, `child` is a value but `new Child` returns a pointer. Also, `Child` does not have a constructor that takes a `Adult*`

Comment: While that would indeed compile, it wouldn't necessarily work. Because you pass in an object, there is the chance that it is allocated in automatic memory, so taking its address is not safe. `my_adult` will become a dangling pointer when `hand` goes out of scope.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Of course it wouldn't necessarily work. But how is he supposed to learn anything if he gets everything served on a silver platter?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign an object to a pointer.  It will not work.  Also Child must be defined before Adult.  Otherwise, Adult must be defined with Child as a pointer (and a forward declaration).